# Most Powerful Test; Two-Parameter Normal Distribution

Tags: hypothesis-testing, normal-distribution, mathematical-statistics, exponential-family

Is it possible to show that the two-parameter Normal distribution has monotone likelihood ratio?

EDIT:

This is actually part of a larger problem. We have a random sample from $\mathcal N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ and are testing: 
\begin{align}
Ho\!:\quad&\sigma <\sigma_o , &\mu &\in \mathbb{R}  \\
Ha\!:\quad&\sigma = \sigma_1 , &\mu &= \mu_1
\end{align}
Construct a most powerful level-$α$ test. My initial thought was to show $\mathcal N(μ,σ^2)$ has the monotone likelihood ratio (MLR), and from there we can construct a uniformly most powerful (UMP) test via the [Karlin-Rubin theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniformly_most_powerful_test#The_Karlin-Rubin_theorem). Any suggestions on general strategy would be appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to the site, @user23658. Would you mind fleshing out your question a little? I'm not sure if it is answerable in its present form.

Comment: Well this is actually part of a larger problem.  We have a random sample from $N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ and are testing:
$H_o: \sigma<\sigma_o, \mu \in \mathbb{R}$ vs. 

$H_a: \sigma=\sigma_1, \mu = \mu_1$

Construct a most powerful level-$\alpha$ test.  My initial thought was to show $N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ has the MLR, and from there we can construct a UMP test via Karlin-Rubin.  Any suggestions on general strategy would be appreciated! Thanks for the response.